# Javascript, string: test string for presence of sub-string that includes an asterisk (*)

Tags: javascript, string, testing, asterisk, indexof

I'm doing a pretty basic string matching test as follows:

```
if(msList.indexOf(textChoice) != -1)
```

This works well *except that* occasionally the sub-string I'm looking for (textChoice) ends with an asterisk. Then I end up getting false matches because the asterisk in the string is interpreted as an operator, not a character in the string.

So how can I do this test so that any asterisks in the sub-string are treated as regular characters?

PS. I know the simple answer is "Don't include asterisks in your sub-string" but they're in the data I'm working with--I can't get rid of them.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that's not working? The `indexOf` function should always treat an asterisk as a regular character anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I think I mis-diagnosed the problem. Solved it another way. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All characters in the substring will be treated as regular characters. `*` is not a special operator and does not change the behavior of `indexOf` in any way. Moreover, the `indexOf` method should never return `false`. It will return:

- `-1` if no match is found or
- starting index of matching substring if found

Note that the starting index can be `0` which does not equate to false for substring searching. It just means that the substring was found in the beginning of the string.

```
"ABC".indexOf("AB") // 0
```

Put explicit checks comparing the return value with `-1` instead of just checking for a truthy value.

```
if("ABC".indexOf("AB")) {
    // will never execute
}
```

Instead, always do this:

```
if("ABC".indexOf("AB") != -1) {
   // ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I misunderstood where the problem was. I was able to fix it another way. I appreciate your help, though. It set me back on the right track.